# How to update the Master fragment list for every 1 min

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a Master Detail fragment in an Activity. Master Fragment has a dynamic list which is query from Sqlite DB. How to update the Master fragment list for every 1 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Handler and its `postDelayed()` to fire Runnable to do the job. Once job its done runnable shall fire itself delayed again. Pseudo code:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

in code, to start the avalanche:

```
mHandler.postDelayed( mRunnable, 60*1000 );
```

and runnable

```
Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // do your job

      mHandler.postDelayed( this, 60*1000 );
   }
}
```